# socket_create vs. fsockopen php

Tags: php, sockets, udp

The hosting service that I use currently does not let me use sockets, probably for good reason on their part. They do, however, let me use *fsockopen*. I was wondering what the difference is, because some scripts that worked with *socket_create* and even *stream_socket_server*, do not work with *fsockopen*. That said, if *fsockopen* should work, my code is listed below. What it does is it listens on its own ip address for incoming udp packets and reads them.

Thanks

```
$sock = fsockopen("udp://x.x.x.x", $port);
while(1)
{
    $buf = fread($sock, 200);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[fsockopen](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) creates a connection to a host, not a listening socket.

fsockopen($address) ~== [socket_connect](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php)([socket_create](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php)(), $address)

Your hosting provider doesn't want you listening on alternate ports/protocols.

If what you have works, I wouldn't count on it always working as it would be a bug.

Comment: thanks "fsockopen == socket_connect(socket_create(), $address)" was exactly what i was looking for. looks like i need to find a new host : P

Comment: where can i get more detailed information for you answer. isn't there be a program listening on port 80? isn't a program listening on 80 a listening socket?

Comment: @JayapalChandran what Samuel wanted to do was write the program that is listening on port 80, not connect to it. He wanted to accept connections (a simplification, since UDP is stateless). This might be a good start if you want to learn more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket

Comment: From my own experience, fsockopen is way slower than socket_connection. fsockopen (just the function) took over 2sec to connect to local server, when socket_create did just the same in few milliseconds :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer!!