# Is this the right way to connect to a socket?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [socket_create vs. fsockopen php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563153/socket-create-vs-fsockopen-php)

Is this the right way to connect to a socket in PHP.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen($ipaddress,$port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} 
else{
echo "Socket connected";
}
echo fread($fp, 100);
?>
```

If yes, then what is the difference between this approach and the approach specified here:
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Socket-Programming-With-PHP/
Thanks