# What is the difference between socket php functions

Tags: php, sockets

What is the difference between the the two following functions:

```
$fp = fsockopen("mydomain.com", 80);
```

and

```
$fp=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
socket_bind($fp, "mydomain.com", 80);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [socket\_create vs. fsockopen php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563153/socket-create-vs-fsockopen-php)

Comment: The second piece of code is a) invalid because socket_bind() expects an address and not a name, and b) used for accepting connections rather than making connections.